# MS Access - VBA call variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA to develop a code which will automatically open an Access' form when a condition is met. Part of the Code is the following:

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefresh

DoCmd.OpenForm "NAME_OF_FORM", acNormal, "", "[NUMBER] = 500", , acHidden
```

Instead of setting "[NUMBER] = 500", I want to give a variable. Let's say:

```
Dim Test as String

Test = 500
```

When I try to run the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "NAME_OF_FORM", acNormal, "", "[NUMBER] = Test", , acHidden
```

The command does not run, but it runs when I give the condition "[NUMBER] = 500".

Can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a string concatenation. You combine two strings with the ampersand: &

```
Dim Test as String
Test = 500

DoCmd.OpenForm "NAME_OF_FORM", acNormal, "", "[NUMBER] =" & Test, , acHidden
```